# Is there a way to time the execution of Selenium scripts in the IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Is there a way to time the execution of Selenium scripts in the IDE? I would like to be able to provide execution times for a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, you just want to see how long it takes to run the test? If that's the case, just grab the system date/time at the beginning of the script like  this:

storeEval | new Date().getTime(); | TestStartTime

Then at the very end, get the system date/time again:

storeEval | new Date().gettime(); | TestEndTime

then subtract TestStartTime from TestEndTime to get the difference in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to set the time of execution for Selenium IDE scripts. One has to manually start the execution of the scripts.

Comment: I wasnt asking for how to set the time to start a test, I was asking to see if there is a way to tell how loong a test takes to execute.